# Auto-set focus in an input field?

Tags: forms, input-focus

[image]

In a form, some info is already filled in. 
By tapping the X as seen in the image above, the user can then enter new info.

**Question**: Would it be a good idea to place the input-focus on that (yellow) input field as soon as the user taps on that "X"?

**Philosophy**: When the user taps on that X, she wants to change that info, so by placing the input-focus in the input field, she can start typing right away without having to tab to or click into the input field.

I know there are several UX faults in that design, but my question is all about the input-focus.

**Update**: We are talking about one and the same input here, just to be clear. Sorry for not being clear on this one.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Set focus on the same input after clearing its value

I'd suggest focusing on the same input after clearing its value because the user intentionally deleted / cleared the value by clicking on 'x' to re-enter a new value.

Shifting focus to somewhere else or next available input definitely causes confusion and probably he/she may get annoyed. The User needs to process the interface again to understand the new changes (the Cognitive Process which includes Visual, Intellect, Motor, etc.).

Imagine the frustration of a user when you have a bunch of form elements that shifts their focus once the respective value is cleared (by clicking on 'x').

For instance: Best Buy clears the value when 'x' clicked, but focuses on the same input and shows the default placeholder.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Yeah you can go ahead with this philosophy if the input is mandatory field.

When it is not mandatory, there is chance that user might just want to remove the information.

I just want to add a thought:

- In case of mobile, screen keyboard appears after autofocus then user will know it is typable.
- In other than mobile, user may simply click even after autofocus
  to confirm that it is typable.